# How can I start the Eclipse IDE with server mode jvm in Linux?

Tags: eclipse

I want to know the changes that I must apply to the eclipse.ini file to start the jvm in server mode instead of client mode. I am using Red Hat 6.

Comment: You may want to consider using the `-XX:+TieredCompilation` option if your JRE supports it, instead of forcing server level compilation. It's a way of getting client-like start up and so on, with long-term large heap server compilation advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass JVM options on the command line when launching Eclipse, or (preferably) add them to `eclipse.ini`. After the `-vmargs` line, add a line to specify the `-server` option. Read [the eclipse.ini wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for more details, especially noting the instructions that say "*one option per line*."